# How can i resolve o problem Failure/Error: let(:currency) { create(:currency) } using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am testing model using rspec and factory Girl

My model

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :countries

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  before_destroy :safe_to_delete

  def safe_to_delete
    countries.any? ? false : true
  end
end
```

My factory girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :currency, class: 'Currency' do
    sequence(:name) { |i| "Currency-#{i}" }
  end
end
```

My currency_spec.rb is

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Currency , type: :model do
  let(:currency) { create(:currency) }
  let(:currency1) { create(:currency) }
  let(:country) { create(:country) }

  describe 'associations' do
    subject {currency}
    it { should have_many(:countries) }
  end

  describe 'validations' do
    subject {currency}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
  end

  describe 'method save_to_delete' do
    context 'case false' do
        before { country.update_column(:currency_id, currency.id)  }
        subject { currency.destroy }
        it { is_expected.to be_falsy }
    end
    context 'case true' do
        before { country.update_column(:currency_id, currency1.id)  }
        subject { currency.destroy }
        it { is_expected.to be_truthy }
    end
  end

end
```

The error is:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:currency) { create(:currency) }

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   A validação falhou: Name não está disponível
```

Even though I disable the presence and uniqueness validations in the model, the problem continues

Who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly create the migration to include the `name` on currencies at database level?

Because I created the migration here locally and the tests passed.

Please take a look on the below code.
It is what I did locally and is working here!

#### 1. Migration

- file: `db/migrate/2021XXXXXXXXXX_create_currencies.rb`

```rb
class CreateCurrencies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :currencies do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

#### 2. Model

- `app/models/currency.rb`

```rb
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :countries

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true # Can be oneliner ;)

  before_destroy :safe_to_delete

  def safe_to_delete
    countries.empty? # Much simpler, right? ;)
  end
end
```

#### 3. Factory

- `spec/factories/currency.rb`

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :currency do
    sequence(:name) { |i| "Currency-#{i}" }
  end
end
```

#### 4. Tests

- `spec/models/currency_spec.rb`

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe Currency, type: :model do
  let(:currency1) { create(:currency) }
  let(:currency2) { create(:currency) }
  let(:country) { create(:country) }

  describe 'associations' do
    subject { currency1 }
    it { should have_many(:countries) }
  end

  describe 'validations' do
    subject { currency1 }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
  end

  describe 'when the currency is being deleted' do
    context 'with countries associated' do
      before { country.update_column(:currency_id, currency1.id)  }
      subject { currency1.destroy }
      it { is_expected.to be_falsy }
    end

    context 'with no countries associated' do
      before { country.update_column(:currency_id, currency2.id)  }
      subject { currency1.destroy }
      it { is_expected.to be_truthy }
    end
  end
end
```

## Test Execution

Finally, the tests should work correctly with the above setup!

- `spec/models/currency_spec.rb`

```rb
rspec spec/models/currency_spec.rb

D, [2021-03-06T03:31:03.446070 #4877] DEBUG -- : using default configuration
D, [2021-03-06T03:31:03.449482 #4877] DEBUG -- : Coverband: Starting background reporting
.....

Top 5 slowest examples (0.10688 seconds, 11.4% of total time):
  Currency when the currency is being deleted with countries associated should be falsy
    0.04095 seconds ./spec/models/currency_spec.rb:23
  Currency associations should have many countries
    0.03529 seconds ./spec/models/currency_spec.rb:10
  Currency when the currency is being deleted with no countries associated should be truthy
    0.01454 seconds ./spec/models/currency_spec.rb:29
  Currency validations should validate that :name cannot be empty/falsy
    0.00812 seconds ./spec/models/currency_spec.rb:15
  Currency validations should validate that :name is case-sensitively unique
    0.00797 seconds ./spec/models/currency_spec.rb:16

Finished in 0.93948 seconds (files took 8.04 seconds to load)
5 examples, 0 failures
```

All tests passed ✅